# Copy file1 name inplace of file2 and add extra to it, but not copy file1 extention

Tags: java, file, copy, filenames, rename

How can i change the name of a file to match the original file and have extra txt in it, please see example below

Original
dataFile.txt
thisNameNeedsToMatchDataFile.txt (but also have ".Step2" added in before the .txt)

Desired output
dataFile.txt
dataFile.Step2.txt

Any help would be appropriated thank you in advanced.

Comment: your question is not totally clear

Comment: My apologies, i have two files, file1 and file2, I need to copy the name from file1 in place of my file2 name, but while its is copying file1 name onto file2 i need to add adition txt to the name of file2, so in the end for example, file1 should look like datafile.txt and file2 should look like datafile.Step2.txt. Sorry I wasn't clear enough again.

Comment: still not clear.. please expend your question with given input, the files.. and desired output.. step by step.. dont put the whole 'logic' into 1 sentence

Comment: and more important, what did you try yourself?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i understand your problem this is how i think the solution could look like
(java 7+)

```
public class FileConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileConverter converter = new FileConverter();
    File newFile1 = new File("c:/parent1/file1.dump");
    File newFile2 = new File("c:/parent2/file2.dump");
    converter.convert2Files(newFile1, newFile2);
}

private void convert2Files(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {
    // compare if the 2 files have the same name
    if(file1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(file2.getName())){
        String newName = file1.getName().substring(0, file1.getName().lastIndexOf('.')); 
        String newNameOriginal = newName + ".txt";
        String newNameStep2 = newName + ".Step2.txt";
        File newFileOriginal = new File(file1.getParent(),newNameOriginal);
        File newFileStep2 = new File(file1.getParent(),newNameStep2);
        Path file = file1.toPath();/* use file1 as source file */
        Path to = Paths.get(file1.getParent());/* path to destination directory */
        Files.copy(file, to.resolve(newFileOriginal.toPath()));
        Files.copy(file, to.resolve(newFileStep2.toPath()));
    }
}
}
```